# Silverlight Domain Data Source + Paging : AutoLoad = "False"

Tags: silverlight, wcf-ria-services, domaindatasource

I want to use a `DataPager` with a `DataGrid` and `DomainDataSource`.

I would like to have future pages cache ahead of time.  When the user gets, say, five pages off from the last page, I would like another XXXX pages to load.  However, I don't want the grid to auto-refresh when parameters (bound to user controls) change, so I have autoload set to false...

Is there a good way to make this work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for the [LoadSize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.domaindatasource.loadsize%28v=VS.91%29.aspx) property. I don't remember the specifics, but it allows you to load multiple pages at a time. For instance, if you set PageSize to 5 and LoadSize to 25, you'll be loading 5 pages of data at a time.